# datetime64 comparison in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime64

I am struggling with datetime64 comparisons in dataframes to update a column. lets say we have a dataframe 'df' with a 'date' column

```
df.date.values[0]
Out[128]: numpy.datetime64('2015-05-17T22:00:00.000000000+0800')
```

i needed to drop the time and just do a date comparison, so to extract the date i use .date()

```
df.date[0].date()
Out[131]: datetime.date(2015, 5, 17)
```

I test it out first

```
df.date[0].date()==np.datetime64('2015-05-17')
Out[132]: True
```

So all seems good i try to do a condition if date column equal to a specific date, update another column into another value

```
df[df.date[0].date()==np.datetime64('2015-05-17')].flag=True
```

I get a KeyError: True

how do i properly do this?

Comment: do you have a column True?

Comment: i have a column call flag i trying to update to True if conditions met

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

`flag = pd.Series(np.where(df.date == np.datetime64('2015-05-17'), True, False), index=df.index)`

flag will be a series of True/False values which you use later.